# Why does copying a code block line contain a trailing newline?

Tags: discussion, markdown, code-formatting

Using macOS and Chrome, triple clicking a line to select and copy in a code block results in a trailing newline. When pasting a command into a shell, this results in the cursor being placed on a line below the command which is undesirable.

#### To reproduce:

1. Visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/11767563/7078832
2. Triple click and copy the first line of the code block
3. Paste somewhere to see the trailing newline

#### Why this is undesirable:

- editing requires extra movement [image: editing requires extra movement]
- shell history is polluted with newline [image: shell history is polluted with newline]
- breaks shell shortcut for last arg of previous command

Comment: My browser (chrome) doesn't support double-click to select the whole line.

Comment: It's not undesirable when pasting into a text editor.  Solution - don't select the line with a double click.

Comment: @rene I believe it's a triple click while on Chrome.

Comment: *destroys mouse button while quadruple triple clicking*

Comment: Sorry, double click should be triple click. I've looked at this a bit more and realized that this seems to be a general phenomena across selecting any text in a browser via triple click, so it's clearly not a result of SE. I guess the alternative to triple click is dragging? Can I file a complaint with all browser makers?

Comment: This post doesn't belongs here as it isn't relevant to meta SE but it seems like it could be potentially useful somewhere...

Comment: @MartinJames it is a genuine problem for shell commands as many of these don't get put in an editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your browser assumes that [whitespace is relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467334/why-does-google-chrome-always-add-space-after-selected-text).

There is a CR/LF in that code block, as can be seen in [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1386273). That your browser selects it is the browsers quirk.

I can trick Chrome into copying a line without additional whitespace as demonstrated below:

```
gem install specific_install
```

The markup of the above line looks like this:

```
<pre><code>gem install specific_install</code></pre>
```

That only works for one line. If you add two

```
gem install specific_install
line two
```

it no longer works.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Whoops, ninja'd ;)

Comment: @Ollie sorry .. next time I'll post a *the flower is typing* message :D